# Can "And so on" be a separate sentence?

Tags: idioms, sentence-structure

I understand that "and so on" normally ends a list. But can I write something like 
"I don't like music, because [...].  I don't like poetry either, because [...]. Nor like I math, since [...]. And so on."?

Comment: I do't think so since _and so on_ means _and similar things_. You can't make a sentence with _and similar things_ because it doesn't express an independent idea. That aside you're making a list and separate the items using a _**,**_ and suddenly you put a stop to this list by a full stop and then continued your list.

Comment: @Yuri I agree, but we have to keep in mind that in less strict forms of writing, especially in creative writing, it's quite possible. For example, check out [this example](https://books.google.com/books?id=3XhzAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA197) (second paragraph, last sentence): *"Indeed, without the action of terrestrial plate tectonics, which depends in part on Earth's internal heat, the chemical and topographic environment at the planet's surface, the interchange among continent, seafloor, and ocean, would be very different . And so on."*

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81439/haruki-murakami-phrases-em-dash-use

Comment: @Damkerng, I wonder, how you have managed to find this example

Comment: @Damkerng T. Thanks, that was enlightening; I didn't know it's actually possible although as a learner I personally prefer to stick to prescriptive writing rules.

Comment: @Serguei I found it in [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/). It's quite useful. ;-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. - You have all the material needed for a strong answer.  Go for it!

Comment: @J.Doe Thanks for the encouragement, but there are some points (actually many) that I'm not sure about. Like, what'd be the best way to phrase it, if we don't want to write it as a sentence fragment like the OP does?, is it that strange to write *[a]nd so on* after *nor do I like ...*? (I think it's probably not that bad, but it's not very good either), what are possible alternatives?, and so on. Just to name a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crediting @Damkerng's insight:

In informal speech and writing, "and so on" is fine as a fragmentary sentence.  It's similar to "etc.", and one can add it after a period, as an afterthought.

To avoid using it as a fragmentary sentence, just move it so it's before the period, e.g.

> My opinion about the famous song "My Favorite Things": I do not like cream colored ponies, or crisp apple strudels, or doorbells or sleigh bells, or schnitzel with noodles, and so on.  But the tune is catchy.

I think that as self-expression, "and so on" would work better *after* the period in my example sentence.  But it's a subtle difference.

(That's not really my opinion.  I just needed some material for an example sentence.)